# Shutdown Events in Android

Tags: android, service, analytics, shutdown

Is it possible to intercept a phone shutdown event or perhaps use a different hack around this? I have an always running service that's part of a non-market application which is collecting some analytics data.  I'd like to tell the analytics to end session and report, then resume the system shutdown.

I've tried triggering the event from the onDestroy or onShutdown parts of the services, but the phone will shutdown without giving it time to report.

Working around this by making many short sessions based on the activity screens yields non-sensical analytics information that I'd like to avoid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Build a broadcast receiver at catches the ACTION_SHUTDOWN intent.

In the onReceive() method you can accomplish what you are trying to do.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SHUTDOWN

Comment: I have this is up and it has passed all tests.

Comment: @TimCapes Awesome to hear! There are so many intents that Android throws.  To help with your data collection you can catch the BOOT_COMPLETE action intent to start your application when the phone is turned on ;)

Comment: Already doing that to launch the service on reboot, but thanks for mentioning it.

Comment: i have already made this class but not able to do that i want.

Comment: i made a class extends boradcastreceiver and also mention it in manifest file, but when i shutdown my device nothing happened, public class ShutdownReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String actionStr = intent.getAction();
    if(Intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN.equals(actionStr)){
Log.d("Shutdown", "Shutting Down");
      
      
     }
    }

} <receiver android:name=".receiver.ShutdownReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN"  />
      </intent-filter>
  </receiver>

Comment: @DeepSan If i'm not mistaken I think that intent.ACTION_SHUTDOWN equals "android.intent.action.ACTION_SHUTDOWN" but your actionStr equals ACTION_SHUTDOWN.  You may want to log both of these to see if they are equal, or create and else statement that will print a different string just to double check the logic.

Comment: @jjNford, sir i have already check this, i tried to print with in if block and without if, as per my observation my shutdown broadcast receiver is not detecting shutdown event...any clear example will be useful, if you can provide.... thanks.

Comment: @DeepSan okay, i see what is going on.  right now your receiver cannot be triggered by any intent outside your application.  change you manifest opening receiver tag to this: <receiver android:name=".receiver.ShutdownReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" >

Comment: @jjNford- hi thanks dude, i have already solved the issue, there was small mistake..anyways thanks a lot for your precious time..

Answer (score 3):

You could try registering a Shutwdown hook using the Runitme [addShutdownHook(Thread hook)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29) method.

Aditionally the method reference states:

> If runFinalizersOnExit(boolean) has been called with a true argument,
>   garbage collection and finalization will take place after all hooks
>   are either finished or have failed. Then the VM terminates.

So, *theoretically* the VM won't terminate until your thread finish.

Comment: Thanks for this idea, it does have some potential.  However, the documentation is rather sparse on when the VM actually gets shutdown, and when the other events happen.  I think given the unclear documentation I'm better off catching the action shutdown.  I'll keep this in mind if I run into any issues with the broadcast receiver approach.

Comment: @TimCapes You are right, the doc is quite unclear on this matter.